# htaccess rewrite remove trailing slash

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following rewrite rules which work perfectly

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\/$ /social/single_post.php?name=$1&t=$2&id=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\/$ /social/user.php?user=$1 [L]
```

Example: http://myurl.com/username/ points to http://myurl.com/social/user.php?user=username

I want to remove the trailing slash from the second rewrite rule so it will return as follows:

Example: http://myurl.com/username points to http://myurl.com/social/user.php?user=username

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /social/user.php?user=$1 [L]
```

The problem is when I do this, the entire domain is redirecting

so: 
http://myurl.com/ points to http://myurl.com/social/user.php?user=

and 
http://myurl.com points to http://myurl.com/social/user.php?user=

Obviously I don't want those last two things happening. How can I modify my htaccess to achieve the desired outcome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\/$ /social/single_post.php?name=$1&t=$2&id=$3 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\/$ /social/user.php?user=$1 [L]
```

Comment: this helped so much thank you. It wasn't the exact result, but the condition statements definitely got me sorted.